# How to sort a report by a calculated field

Tags: reporting-services, report, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a simple report made with FetchXml that shows something like this:

```
EMPLOYEE NAME             AUTH TOTAL           DRAFT TOTAL 
new_UserName                Exp1*                Exp2*
```

*Exp1:

```
=FormatCurrency(Sum(Fields!lead1_new_totalauthorizedamountValue.Value))
```

*Exp2:

```
=FormatCurrency(Sum(Fields!lead1_new_totalfeescollectedValue.Value)- Sum(Fields!lead1_web_totalrefundamountValue.Value))
```

Here is the issue: I can't realize how sort the whole table by Draft Total or by Auth Total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each group, go to properties, and in sorting enter the expressions you mention.

For the detail, go to properties and in sorting use the same expressions without the aggregation (SUM)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm checking it

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get what are you doing reference when you say 'For details'

Comment: A report can have group's and plain rows without aggregations (detail). In the detail, if you have one in your report, you should use the same expression without SUM function eg. =FormatCurrency(Fields!lead1_new_totalauthorizedamountValue.Value) instead of =FormatCurrency(Sum(Fields!lead1_new_totalauthorizedamountValue.Value))

Comment: Thanks a lot!. Sadly I've tried sorting in that way but the result was not the expected. However I found that the sort by default in the report, luckily, was the column I was trying to sort. Thanks again